# How else can I ship data from zipkin to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, devops, elastic-stack, zipkin

I am trying to ship spans to elasticsearch from zipkin. Both are on separate servers. I have used the following command with correct host ip and port to run zipkin:

`jar "zipkin.jar" -DSTORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch -DES_HOSTS=http://hostname:port`

The zipkin application runs with no issues and I can see traces within the zipkin UI being received in real time. However, the zipkin indicies do not reach the box or they are not visible when searching for the zipkin index. I have tried to restart the elasticsearch and zipkin services. I have also tried to run the command without the -D prefixes. I have also tested whether the zipkin server can communicate with the elasticsearch server using the following command:

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://hostname:port/_cat/indices?v&pretty" -Credential (Get-Credential)`

The zipkin server is able to communicate with the elasticsearch server and retrieve the existing indicies but not the zipkin ones. The log files for both elasticsearch and zipkin do not show any issues at all. I am running java 8 on my zipkin box and I am running zipkin version 2.21.1. The elasticsearch version I am running is 8.7.1. Not sure what else I can do to ship from zipkin to elasticsearch so any help will be appreciated!